# Trigger on update that updates one field if another changes to a certain value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to create a trigger on update. There are two tables involved, cylinder and jobs. When the statusId in the cylinder changes to a certain value say 2 it changes a flag field in both tables. The cylinder table is update quite frequently. I believe I need to check the inserted and deleted tables it see if the statusId field changes to my value of 2.

Here are simple versions of my tables. They are related thru jobNumb

```
CREATE TABLE Cylinder (
    cylinderId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    jobNumb int NOT NULL,
    statusId int,
    flag int
)

CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    jobId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    jobNumb int NOT NULL,
    statusId int,
    reShip int,
    flag int
)
```

Comment: Does the value every change from 2?  Can you give more examples of the rules?

Comment: The value changes to about 40 different values. 2 represents that the cylinder shipped out. The end result is when the value changes to 2 the trigger checks the jobs table to see if it will be coming back. If it is the flags are set in each table. The flags will be changed back when the cylinder comes back to the plant.

Comment: after the cylinder ships out the statusId can still be changed by other things in the system before it comes back. I'm looking for a way to flag that it left and came back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need 2 different update statements since an update statement can only ever update a single table.
However, if the flag in both tables should always be the same value for related rows, you can achieve this by adding a foreign key constraint with `on update cascade` on this column.

A trigger for update would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ON Cylinder 
FOR UPDATE
AS

    -- updates jobs flag
    UPDATE j
    SET flag = CASE WHEN i.statusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- or whatever values suited for your flag
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON(i.cylinderId = d.cylinderId AND i.statusId <> d.statusId)
    INNER JOIN Jobs j ON(i.jobNumb = j.jobNumb)

    -- updates cyliner flag
    UPDATE c 
    SET flag = CASE WHEN i.statusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- or whatever values suited for your flag
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON(i.cylinderId = d.cylinderId AND i.statusId <> d.statusId)
    INNER JOIN Cylinder c ON(i.jobNumb = c.jobNumb)

GO
```